# Why blend does not see a ViewModel and its properties?

Tags: visual-studio, mvvm, windows-phone, viewmodel, blend

I defined a property in a ViewModel class like this:

```
public class MenuHubSectionVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Uri _logoImage;
    public Uri LogoImage
    {
        get
        {
            return _logoImage;
        }
        set
        {
            _logoImage = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("_logoImage");
        }
    }

    #region Prop changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I use MVVM Light and in the ViewModelLocator' s constructor I have:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MenuHubSectionVM>();
```

then:

```
public MenuHubSectionVM MenuHubVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MenuHubSectionVM>();
        }
    }
```

but when I try to make a Data binding to it in blend the IDE does not see this
MenuHubSectionVM and LogoImage property? Why? Also it finds SettingsViewModel (which is defined the same way), but when I click the little arrow next to it, does not find its properties inside?

[image]

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using

Comment: Have you complied your project before using the Binding IDE? The IDE can only detect Types form compiled assembly

Comment: I think you need to expand the model, it does have those properties. Also you have a typo here -   NotifyPropertyChanged("_logoImage");
change  it to   NotifyPropertyChanged("LogoImage");

Comment: That was it. The compilation before the Blend did the trick. Thank you!